# Data type conversion failed when converting date and/or time from string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select distinct 
    format(dateadd(day, 8- datepart(weekday, dlv_hdr.actual_goods_movement_dt),  
    cast(dlv_hdr.actual_goods_movement_dt as date)), 'MM/dd/yyyy')  as "Week End Date"
from 
    can_delivery.sap_delivery_header_data dlv_hdr
```

I'm getting the error shown below while running this SQL Server code in SSMS. The data type of column `actual_goods_movement_dt` is `varchar(20)` and data is in `yyyymmdd` format. I tried many solutions available but non of them worked for me. Your help is appreciated

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? You can probably identify junk data like this: `SELECT {key column(s)}, actual_goods_movement_dt FROM can_delivery.sap_delivery_header_data WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, actual_goods_movement_dt) IS NULL AND actual_goods_movement_dt IS NOT NULL;`?

Comment: ^ and once you find the junk data, fix it, and then change the data type to the right one.

Comment: Are you sure that you are sure that the data is always in that format ?

Comment: If the data is always in format `yyyyMMdd` then it should be [this simple](https://dbfiddle.uk/PqQthZEr)

Comment: Even with your query it works [see this](https://dbfiddle.uk/PoEv_4QX)

Comment: yep, there was junk date value like 00000000 which was causing that issue, after removing junk value code worked perfectly. than you @RhythmWasaLurker

Comment: Issue has been resolved now, thank you for your time @GuidoG

Comment: ^ code worked with varchar data type, I didn't had to change its type, also type change could cause data loss I guess @RhythmWasaLurker

Comment: You don't have to change the data type, no, but that sure would prevent junk data values like 00000000 ever getting in there again, right?

Comment: Storing data in the wrong datatype will always be a danger, you would do yourself a great favor if you fixed the design and change the datatype to the correct datatype. Not only will it prevent junk values, but it will make searching better (then you can search on year or month or dates between and so on...)